# Show/Hide buttons based on inline code while looping

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how to use a temporary variable (created from a loop) to show/hide a button.
I have tabular data and some action buttons to the side of them. I need to be able to turn buttons off and on based on the state of that data.

f.IsFoo is a boolean

```
 <table stuff here>
 <% foreach (Foo f in listOfFoos) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Fubar(f)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Fubar1(f) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Fubar2(f)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Fubar3(f)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Fuba4(f)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Fubar5(f)%>
        </td>
        <td>

        <asp:Button Text="Load" runat="server"  OnClick="FooBar" Visible='<%= f.IsFoo%>'/>

        </td>
    </tr>
<%}%>
```

I'm pretty new to aspx and it's syntax and online searches have just confused me more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I tend to put logic like this in the code behind file - however I believe the code below should work,

I added an ID to your button - and I also removed the visibility property - I'm then referencing the button, by its ID - and setting its visibility equal to that of the f.IsFoo property

Possibly try this here:

```
<% btnFoo.Visible = f.IsFoo; %>

<asp:Button ID="btnFoo" Text="Load" runat="server"  OnClick="FooBar" />
```

Comment: If I set an ID on my button in a loop, does every button on that page have that ID? Or just the last? How does that work?

Comment: Every button on your page will have an ID, however the HTML that asp.net generates will generate a unique ID - for example the html output might look like ID="this_that_btnFoo_1"

Comment: if you test this out - then view the source - you can see what it outputs

Comment: yeah I guess my real question is am I going to have trouble doing this in a loop?

Comment: No - it should work fine, I duplicated and tested locally (as much as I could) with no problems - try out my code and let me know if you have problems or questions.

Comment: Got back to my computer, and yes it did! Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27979/discussion-between-sam-jarman-and-loren)